# Transformer rectifier set. A question about the schematic diagram

Tags: transformer, power-electronics, rectifier, electrical

This is a high voltage transformer (53kV) and rectifier that is used to power an Electrostatic Precipitator. The schematic shows a jumper between terminals H1 and H2 with a label "Remove jumper for half wave operation". Can anyone explain the benefit of operating the rectifier at half-wave rectification?

Also, the schematic shows 2 separate surge arrestors. Why is this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Large plate precipitators generally require a continuous DC source, hence, full wave.  Older, smaller plate precipitators typically use a pulsed DC source.  Half wave rectification accomplishes this.

Large Plate precipitators are generally more efficient.

Comment: can u explain what 45 kv DC full load meaning?

Comment: It appears that that is just the continuous full load voltage rating of the rectifier, but that it can handle peak voltages of 75 kV before breaking down.